# Locate rows with 0 value columns and set them to none pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Data:

```
f a b
5 0 1
5 1 3
5 1 3
5 6 3
5 0 0
5 1 5
5 0 0
```

I know how to locate the rows with both columns being `0`, setting them to `None` on the other hand is a mystery.

```
df_o[(df_o['a'] == 0) & (df_o['d'] == 0)]
# set a and b to None
```

Expected result:

```
f a b 
5 0 1
5 1 3
5 1 3
5 6 3
5 None None
5 1 5
5 None None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If working with numeric values `None` is converted to `NaN` and integers to `float` by design:

```
df_o.loc[(df_o['a'] == 0) & (df_o['b'] == 0), ['a','b']] = None

print (df_o)
     a    b
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  3.0
2  1.0  3.0
3  6.0  3.0
4  NaN  NaN
5  1.0  5.0
6  NaN  NaN
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all `True`s per rows with `axis=1`:

```
df_o.loc[(df_o[['a', 'b']] == 0).all(axis=1), ['a','b']] = None
print (df_o)
     a    b
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  3.0
2  1.0  3.0
3  6.0  3.0
4  NaN  NaN
5  1.0  5.0
6  NaN  NaN
```

**Details**:

```
print ((df_o[['a', 'b']] == 0))
       a      b
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4   True   True
5  False  False
6   True   True

print ((df_o[['a', 'b']] == 0).all(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Updated the question, there are more then just those two columns.

Comment: What does `axis=1` do in this case?

Comment: It check if all `True`s per rows.

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of is like this. Create an extra copy of the dataframe and check both individually while setting the value to None on the main dataframe. Not the cleanest solutions but:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['f'] = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
df['a'] = [0,1,1,6,0,1,0]
df['b'] = [1,3,3,3,0,5,0]

df1 = df.copy()
df['a'] = np.where((df.a == 0) & (df.b == 0), None, df.a)
df['b'] = np.where((df1.a == 0) & (df1.b == 0), None, df.b)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   f     a     b
0  5     0     1
1  5     1     3
2  5     1     3
3  5     6     3
4  5  None  None
5  5     1     5
6  5  None  None
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.replace(0, np.nan)` -- to get NaNs (possibly more useful)
`df.replace(0, 'None')` -- what you actually want

Comment: Not sure, since this just replaces `0` with `None`, we need to set `None` with a condition. Or do you mean with my filter and your "suffix"?

Comment: Sorry - misread your query. Jezraels boolean approach is good (as per).

Answer (score 0):

It is surely not the most elegant way to do this, but maybe this helps.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': [0,1,1,6,0,1,0],
        'b':[1,3,3,3,0,5,0]}

df_o = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df_None = df_o[(df_o['a'] == 0) & (df_o['b'] == 0)]
df_o.loc[df_None.index,:] = None
print(df_o)
```

Out:

```
    a    b
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  3.0
2  1.0  3.0
3  6.0  3.0
4  NaN  NaN
5  1.0  5.0
6  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
import pandas as pd


a = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 6, 0, 1, 0])
b = pd.Series([1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 5 ,0])

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})


v = [[data[i][j] for i in data] == [0, 0] for j in range(len(data['a']))]   # spot null rows

a = [None if v[i] else a[i] for i in range(len(a))]
b = [None if v[i] else b[i] for i in range(len(b))]

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})


print(data)
```

Output:

```
     a    b
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  3.0
2  1.0  3.0
3  6.0  3.0
4  NaN  NaN
5  1.0  5.0
6  NaN  NaN
```